# Fill duplicates with missing value after grouping with some logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I need to take off the duplicates of ticket_id if the owner_type is the same, and if not, pick 'm' over 's', if no value is picket then a NaN is returned:

`data = pd.DataFrame({'owner_type':['m','m','m','s','s','m','s','s'],'ticket_id':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})`

```
'|    | owner_type   |   ticket_id |
 |---:|:-------------|------------:|
 |  0 | m            |           1 |
 |  1 | m            |           1 |
 |  2 | m            |           2 |
 |  3 | s            |           2 |
 |  4 | s            |           3 |
 |  5 | m            |           3 |
 |  6 | s            |           4 |
 |  7 | s            |           4 |'
```

Should give back:

```
'|    | owner_type   |   ticket_id |
 |---:|:-------------|------------:|
 |  0 | m            |         NaN |
 |  1 | m            |         NaN |
 |  2 | m            |           2 |
 |  3 | s            |         NaN |
 |  4 | s            |         NaN |
 |  5 | m            |           3 |
 |  6 | s            |         NaN |
 |  7 | s            |         NaN |'
```

Pseudo code would be like : If ticket_id is duplicated, look at owner_type, if owner_type has mover than one value, return value of 'm' and NaN for 's'.

My attempt

```
data.groupby('ticket_id').apply(lambda x: x['owner_type'] if len(x) < 2 else NaN)
```

Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df['ticket_id'].where(
    ~df.duplicated(['owner_type','ticket_id'],keep=False) & 
    df['owner_type'].eq(df.groupby('ticket_id')['owner_type'].transform('min'))))
```

Old answer:

```
m = ~df.duplicated(keep=False) & df['owner_type'].eq('m')
df['ticket_id'].where(m)
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    3.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
```

Comment: Just one question, what if I had more columns? I tried to simplify my example but when I try to do the df.duplicated(keep=False) I can't specify columns. Imagine I had more columns with which are not duplicated besides owner_type and ticket_id, is there still a choice?

Comment: you can specify columns in `duplicated()`. `df.duplicated(subset = ['col1','col2'...],keep=False)`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: having another question, the logic shared would not work if there is a row not duplicated and the owner_type is s, could you please assist me on what I would have to change? @rhug123